# Parallax effect on UITableView with an horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, parallax

I created a parallax view on a tableview putting an horizontal scrollview behind the headerTableView.

I set `tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

then the `tableView.headerTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

and set my scrollView like that :

```
[self.view insertSubview:scrollView belowSubview:tableview];
```

The parallax effect works perfectly but my issue is that the user cannot interact with the horizontal scrollview since it's behind the tableView;

I tried to put the `tableView.headerTableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` but it does not work.

If I want to interact with the scrollView I need to set the `tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` but then I cannot interact with the tableView anymore.

Is there a tricky way to be able to interact with the scrollView and the tableView and keep the parallax effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to pass touches 'through' a view, you could override the hitTest on a View and pass the hit to another one.

In my case, I had a quite narrow scrollview, put it into a larger container and set it as a property (touchReceivingView). On the container, I used the following code to pass the hitTest to the other view:

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return touchReceivingView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable the userInteraction to the horizontal scrollview and implement `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to catch the user's swipe?
After that, you can programmatically "move" the horizontal scrollview according to the event fired by the recognizer

Comment: I though about that but I found it a bit too hacky. Is it how other apps do?

Comment: hmm...I never noticed it and yes, probably it's too hacky